# React native color a letter partially

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native

I'm making a React Native Karaoke app and I need to do an animation in which a letter is colored from left to right.

Is it possible to apply color to, say, half of a letter?

[image]

Comment: Yea, you have to stack text on top of each other and animate the width of the text that is on top which would be red. It would be hard to do for a song unless you manually timed it which would still be a pita. Desktop application that could parse mp3 codecs would be the best way to go tho.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from my comment, Here is how this type of styling is done. Instead of on hover, you would just animate the width with javascript.

```css
p{
color: black;
position: relative;
display: inline-block;
margin: 0;
font-size: 50px;
}
p:before{
content: attr(data-c);
position: absolute;
width: 0;
overflow:hidden;
top: 0;
left: 0;
color:red;
transition: width 1s;
}
p:hover:before{
width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<p data-c="Hello">Hello</p>
```

Comment: Setting width just makes the text flow to next line instead of hiding it, even though i set overflow to hidden: https://snack.expo.io/BkCus_KVf

Comment: Use `white-space: nowrap;`

Comment: Doesn't seem applicable to React Native. Can you get it to work on the expo link i gave?

Answer (score 0):

I tried this you may further apply more animation to it:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  Text,
  View,
  Animated
} from 'react-native';

export default class AnimatedText extends Component{

  componentWillMount() {
    this.animatedValue = new Animated.Value(0);
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    Animated.timing(this.animatedValue, {
      toValue: 200,
      duration: 2500
    }).start();
  }

  render() {
    const interpolateColor = this.animatedValue.interpolate({
      inputRange: [0, 200],
      outputRange: ['rgb(255,255,255)', 'rgb(255, 0, 0)'],
      extrapolate: "clamp"
    })
    const animatedStyle = {
      color: interpolateColor,
    }
    return (
      <View style={{flex: 1,justifyContent: 'center',alignItems: 'center',padding:10,backgroundColor:'black'}}>
        <Animated.Text style={animatedStyle}>
        May be one day so don't turn on the lights I'll give you what you like Give you what you like
        </Animated.Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: This animates color change for entire text, I need to animate across the text instead, attempting to interpolate the width but it's overflowing: https://snack.expo.io/BkCus_KVf

Answer (score 0):

Your solution in expo works if you set a height restriction: https://snack.expo.io/Bko7oYvr7